# calling RouterModule.forChild() outside the imports array

Tags: angular-router

We are using a CoreModule.forRoot(options) method for a library with some options. Based on one option we need to inject extra routes with RouterModule.forChild([]). Can we call RouterModule.forChild from a forRoot method or later on in the setup? Because now we are calling forChild in the imports array of the CoreModule. But this is not dynamic enough for our case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to push it in the router config array like so:

```
if(addNotFoundRoute){
    this.router.config.push({ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent });
}
```

You could do this in the module constructor (or in an app initializer probably).

When you do this you also need to mark the component for the route as an entry component because otherwise you get an error:

```
entryComponents: [
    PageNotFoundComponent
]
```